# Evaluate : $\int_0^1 \frac{dx}{\sqrt[3]{1-x^3}}$.

Tags: calculus, integration

Evaluate : $$ \int_0^1 \frac{\mathrm{d} x}{\sqrt[3]{1-x^3}}.$$

---

if you feel that this integral is easy, just post hints.

Comment: But can't this be done without knowledge of Beta or Gamma function?  Answer $2\pi 3^{-3/2}$ I guess.

Comment: Okay, but just wait a moment, maybe someone has an idea, this problem is from "Klub Prepa".

Comment: @GEdgar Yes, it can be done, see my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need any beta- or gamma-functions for this integral. I will deal with indefinite integral, you should take care of the limits.

Use the substitution 
$$
1-\frac{1}{x^3}=t^3.
$$

Then, you have
$$
x=\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{1-t^3}},\quad dx=\frac{t^2\,dt}{(1-t^3)^{4/3}},\quad \sqrt[3]{1-x^3}=-\frac{t}{\sqrt[3]{1-t^3}}.
$$
Plugging everything in, you get
$$
-\int \frac{t}{1-t^3}dt,
$$
which can be integrated using standard methods (e.g., partial fractions).

The big question is how would I know about this substitution? You can find a recipe in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/267122/how-to-compute-int-sqrt-fracx2-3x11dx/267175#267175).

Comment: I like it.  It really is elementary.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** Make the change of variables $ t=x^3 $ and then use the beta function.

**Added:** Another way to go is by expanding the integrand in terms of power series as 
$$ \int_0^1 \frac{\mathrm{d} x}{\sqrt[3]{1-x^3}}.= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}{-\frac{1}{3} \choose k}(-1)^k \int_{0}^{1} x^{3k} dx = \dots, $$

where $ {n \choose k}=\frac {n!}{(n-k)!k!} .$ I think you can proceed now.

Comment: thank you, but this was intended for Analysis II, I think there is a solution without the beta function.

Comment: @aziiri I learn beta function on analysis II :)

Comment: in our university, Analysis II is in the second semester of the first year (LMD system), Beta function is not used at this level.

Comment: @aziiri: See the added.

Comment: So, you don't have to know Gamma function, but [for your definition ${n \choose k}=\frac {n!}{(n-k)!k!}$] you do have to know $(1/3)!$ ...

Answer (score 4):

Substitute $u = 1-x^3$ and recall the definition of a beta function:

$$B(m,n) = \int_0^1 du\: u^{m-1} (1-u)^{n-1} = \frac{\Gamma(m) \Gamma(n)}{\Gamma(m+n)}$$